# how to extract this particular html tag with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website with python and beautiful soup and I cannot seem to get this one tag right. How to extract page information?
This is the html code:

```html
<div class="pull-right">
    
      <span class="pages">page 1 / 7</span>
    
      <span class="sep">|</span>
      <a href="#" id="page-next">Next »</a>
    
  </div>
```

I have done this :

```
page=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"pages"})
```

and produced this output: [page 1 / 7]. However I only want a part of this("1/7! or "page 1/7").
Can anyone help?

Comment: `findall` returns a list, so `page[0]` would equal `"page 1 / 7"`  is that what you want?

Comment: `find_all` returns a list. So just take the first element?

Comment: the two commenters above are correct. but the larger question is - what do you want returned if `find_all` finds more than one occurrence of `class:pages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying is giving you a list, where all the elements having same tags will be captured. An easy fix could be access element by index which is '0' but in some case it can be problem as it will get all the 
values having same tag values

if you just want the 'page 1/7' use this

Code:

```
element = soup.find("span",{"class": "pages"})
if bool(element):
    print(element.text)
```

Output:

```
page 1 / 7
```

If you want just '1/7' as your answer use regex.

```
re.findall(r'\d*\s*\/\s*\d*', element.text)[0]
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is

```
page= soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class": "pages"})
page=page.get_text()
```

Try this, hope it will help you

Comment: This answer will throw error.It should be `page= soup.find("span",attrs={"class": "pages"})` or `page= soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class": "pages"})[0]`

Comment: @MohitChandel right now it is not but in case if this particular is somehow gets missing then it will be a problem.

Comment: @Mohit : run this code you will get list object have no attribute text.since you used find_all()